# Im trying to fetch some data in apollo graphql and then use the data in different components without passing props im new to Apollo ;)

Tags: reactjs, redux, graphql, react-apollo

Sup guys im kinda new to apollo and i was reading the documentation but it still a little bit vague. I have a blog page where i have a few components blog header thats where my profile is and title and then a body. But i dont wanne fetch on two components i wanne fetch at parent component and use it on different components just like redux can someone help me out

```
const classes = useStyles();
  const { data, loading } = useFetchSingleBlogQuery({
    variables: { id: 2 }
  });
```

here is my basic fetch and im searching on id which i will pass as a match.params in react

and im using typescript btw just so you know ;)

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking here. Are you asking whether you can fetch the same query across multiple components?

Comment: you can use the same query in many places using cached data, search for "cache only"

Comment: Look at my root component i have an id in the url. that id i pass in the query variables. But i want to use the same data on different components without fetching it again. Just like redux, you fetch it once and it stores in the store and i can access it from multiple components.